# VBA: Split and change string

Tags: string, vba

I need to change e.g. following string `153,154,155,156`

to `153**,**154**,**155**,**156`

so the `,` to `**,**`

How can I do that in VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`Replace()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN

```
Sub ReplaceInStr()

    Dim str As String
    str = "153,154,155,156"
    str = Replace(str, ",", "**,**")
    MsgBox str

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Not better, but different:

```
Sub SplitJoin()

    Debug.Print Join(Split("153,154,155,156", ","), "**,**")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dim s as String
s = "153,154,155,156"
s = Replace(s, ",", "**,**")
```