# Excel VBA cell with delimited values to a list

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that I need to manipulate. I know a bit of VBA but not really enough to automate this.

The spreadsheet is in the following format

```
Cell1   Cell2  Cell3  Cell4
a       b      c      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
a       d      e      1 3 5 
a       f      g      7-8
```

(yes, they have used a variety of delimiters)

I just need to split Cell4 into new rows and for Cells1-3 to be on each line.

```
a       b      c      1
b       b      c      2
etc...
```

I've tried recording both the macros for splitting the text and for transposing, but I can't get my head round the insert of the new lines etc. 
Any help please?

Comment: post your recorded code. tell us where it fails and whats not working so we can help u fix it. [this is how you split strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087921/vba-split-and-change-string/17088028#17088028) and this is how to use [different delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587077/vba-search-in-column-for-specific-character-extract-string-upto-that-character/16588396#16588396)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete solution

```
Sub newmac()

    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim rowOffset As Long
    Dim rowCurrent As Long
    Dim subRow As Long
    Dim c() As String

    rowOffset = 0
    rowCount = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge

    For i = 1 To rowCount
        rowCurrent = i + rowOffset
        c = Split(Cells(rowCurrent, 4), ",")
        If (UBound(c) <= 0) Then c = Split(Cells(rowCurrent, 4), " ")
        If (UBound(c) <= 0) Then c = Split(Cells(rowCurrent, 4), "-")
        ' more than 1 item. process
        If (UBound(c) > 0) Then

            Cells(rowCurrent, 4) = c(0)

            For j = 1 To UBound(c)
                subRow = rowCurrent + j
                range("A" & rowCurrent & ":D" & rowCurrent).Copy
                range("A" & subRow & ":D" & subRow).Insert
                Cells(subRow, 4) = c(j)
            Next j
            rowOffset = rowOffset + UBound(c)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

My Result:

```
a   b   c   1
a   b   c   2
a   b   c   3
a   b   c   4
a   b   c   5
a   b   c   6
a   d   e   1
a   d   e   3
a   d   e   5
a   f   g   7
a   f   g   8
```

Comment: @MikeH: This code works now, I had a mistake with the ubound which is why the dash delimiter didn't work -- it only had two elements.

Comment: Fabulous Daniel, I'll give it a spin, I'm getting a compile error on the c = Split(Cells(rowCurrent, 4), ",") line, but I'm pretty sure I can work that out. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I just copied it straight into a new workbook and it worked fine.  I'm using Excel 2010 if that makes a difference.  Good luck.

Comment: That's sorted it, I tried it again and it's worked - you star, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this to insert one blank row

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).EntireRow.Resize(1).Insert
```